# How to attach a JSON web token in axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

In React i send the data and Headers like below:

```
 axios.post("http://localhost:3000/stockdata",{
                    // data
                    },{headers: {
                        'authorization': "Bearer "+LocalStorage.get('token'),
                        'Accept' : 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
```

In Index.js
//required all the modules

```
    var stockDataRouter = require('./Routers/stockDataRouter')
    app.use('/stockdata', authenticateToken, stockDataRouter)

    app.route('/login')
    .options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req,res)=>{ res.sendStatus(200)})
    .post(cors.cors, (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.header)
    if(req.body.username==='admin' && req.body.password==='password'){
        const user = {
            username: req.body.username,
        }
        jwt.sign({user:user}, 'secretkey',(err, token)=>{
        res.json({
                token: token
            })      
        })
          }
          else{
              res.sendStatus(403)
          }
      })

    function authenticateToken(req,res,next){
        const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']
        console.log(req.headers)
        if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined'){
            const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
            const bearerToken = bearer[1];
            req.token = bearerToken;
            next();
        }
        else{
            console.log('hihihi')
            res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    }
```

if the request have the token then it wont go into the else part ,i can access the stockdata endpoint. but even though am passing the token properly as you can see it in chrome dev tools. Why its not getting reflected in the backend.

req.headers is not having authorization in it.

[image]

In chrome dev tools We can clearly see the Token

[image]

how to solve this?

Comment: Check the returned value from `LocalStorage.get('token')` - It is probably undefined and removed by the agent.

Comment: Most probably `LocalStorage` does not have the `token`

Comment: LocalStorage.get('token') is returning a token.

Comment: You are splitting the `bearerHeader` that means you need to pass it like `'authorization': "Bearer " + LocalStorage.get('token'),` from the client side

Comment: Even if i do tha.t i cant able to recieve that in my backend. if i do console.log(req.headers) I cant able to get that token In my backend

Answer (score 0):

Check in Request Headers in chrome DevTools or etc. Is **authorization** presented there?

[image]

What is on BE side, may be you should check it?

Comment: where to check this in chrome? please help me

Comment: press `Ctrl+shift+i` to open developer tools. Then go to the Network Tab and see if the request is recorded with authorization. You can also click `Inspect` in the context menu (Right click menu) to open the developer tools

Comment: As you can see, authorization is there. Check BE side. What server you use? And what value you log in the console?

Comment: sorry, Whats BE side?

Comment: He meant Back End Side

Comment: Server side (backend)

Comment: In backend side The problem is only with the authenticateToken function. if i remove it my application is performing normally(but without JWT). if i add this functionality i cant see the Bearer Token in the backend which is necessary for jwt.verify() in the endpoints.

Comment: If you use jwt I assume your request header should look like this  

{
Authorization: "Bearer "  + LocalStorage.get('token')
}

Can you provide more info about your server (libs, frameworks and etc.)

Comment: On client side you do axios.post("http://localhost:3000/post".... trying to submit data to the route "/post", in your express app you set middleware for path "'/stockdata'" -  app.use('/stockdata', authenticateToken, stockDataRouter). May be you add headers param to wrong request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your client side code to

```
//Try like this
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers.Authorization =  "Bearer " + LocalStorage.get('token');
    return config;
});

axios.post("http://localhost:3000/post",{
                    // data
                    },{headers: {
                       // 'authorization': "Bearer " + LocalStorage.get('token'),
                        'Accept' : 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
```

as you are splitting the authorization string at the backend

Comment: Even if i do tha.t i cant able to recieve that in my backend. if i do console.log(req.headers) I cant able to get that token In my backend

Comment: Can you show the whole middleware? The Authentication middleware

Comment: have a look at my post which is having the index.js file.

Comment: Can you try `{ Authorization: "Bearer " + LocalStorage.get('token') }`? I can see `authorizat` in your `access-control-request-headers` Header. Notice I've not wrapper the `Authorization` inside quotes

Comment: after i changed like you mentioned i got  'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization,content-type',

Comment: But still no progress

Comment: I've edited my answer to use a different method to attach token to the header. See if it helps

Comment: In your network tab, The Token is wrapped in double quotes. Maybe that's causing some issue. Try removing those extra double quotes from token when you are saving it to LocalStorage

Comment: Or just try `LocalStorage.get('token').replace(/^"|"$/g, "")`

Comment: Its resolved Thank you, guys. There was some CORS problem that caused me this issue.